# Docker on nvidia Jetson Nano not executing

Tags: docker, ubuntu, nvidia-jetson-nano

I am setting up a nvidia jetson nano to run docker containers. I am using an installation procedure that I already used on my x86_64 Ubuntu 16.04 machine, where docker runs smoothely. Nonetheless, docker seems to be set up correctly, but I can't run it.

I flashed the jetson SD card as described in http://nvidia.com/jetsonnano-start, and set up language etc via keyboard and screen.
After that I went headless and installed via ssh. The commands I used are shown in the listing below.

```sh
# in case apt-get is interrupted, e.g. if board freezes, use: $ sudo dpkg --configure -a

sudo apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade

# install Docker, from https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/
sudo apt install -y \
     git \
     apt-transport-https \
     ca-certificates \
     curl \
     gnupg2 \
     software-properties-common

# Get the Docker signing key for packages
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/$(. /etc/os-release; echo "$ID")/gpg | sudo apt-key add -

# Add the Docker official repos
echo "deb [arch=arm64] https://download.docker.com/linux/$(. /etc/os-release; echo "$ID") \
     $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | \
    sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list

# Install Docker
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install -y docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
# starting Docker and enabling it at boot
sudo systemctl enable docker
sudo systemctl start docker

# ad user to docker group, so docker commands can be executed without sudo
sudo gpasswd -a $USER docker
newgrp docker

# install docker-compose
sudo apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev libffi6 libffi-dev libssl-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libjpeg8-dev zlib1g-dev
sudo -H pip install docker-compose
```

and after installation, I can see

```sh
$ docker --version
Docker version 19.03.2, build 6a30dfc
```

however, when excuting something, I get exec format errors

```sh
$ docker run jupyter/minimal-notebook
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"
```

Docker does pull the image. And in Dockerfiles, the `WORKDIR` command works, but `RUN` commands yield the same 'exec format error'.

Any help or hint on how to the this to run without errors is greatly appreciated

Comment: `docker run hello-world` yields the expected output, as does `docker container run alpine echo "Hello World"`

Comment: i also come up with this problem, do you fix it ? thanks

Comment: in the meantime the jetson broke down and had to be replaced. getting back to this in a week or so..

Comment: with the new and working jetson nano, I still have the same issue. no solution in sight..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the architecture of the jetson nano is aarch64 (64 bit ARM). There is no Anaconda build for this, but a project called Archiconda exists that steps into the gap.

See:
https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1051415/jetson-nano/anaconda-for-jetson-nano/

for a jupyter notebook from Docker on a Jetson Nano, it helped me to follow this Dockerfile (as from the link above):
https://github.com/helmuthva/jetson/blob/master/workflow/deploy/ml-base/src/Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

Docker is not a complete virtual machine. Programs build for x86_64 will not run on an incompatible processor. You need to build and use aarch64 versions of the Docker, that may require building from the source.

Many important Python packages contain the C/C++ core that may be incompatible as well, but Python compiles them during installation.